# azure mysql database replication with on-prem mysql master is failing with 2003 error

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-mysql-database

I have setup azure mysql master database and I would like to do data-in replication with an on-prem mysql database but the replication is failing. Can someone tell me the reason ?

I am able to connect azure mysql to on-prem mysql master

running the change to master command below on azure mysql:

azure mysql -

```
+------------+
| VERSION()  |
+------------+
| 5.7.29-log |
+------------+
CALL mysql.az_replication_change_master('xx.xxx.xx.xx', 'abcd', 'abcd', 3306, 'bin.000141', 12176221, 'cert');
CALL mysql.az_replication_start;

mysql> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: xx.xxx.xx.xx
                  Master_User: abcd
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: bin.000141
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 12175973
               Relay_Log_File: relay_bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: bin.000141
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: mysql.%,information_schema.%,performance_schema.%,sys.%
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 12175973
              Relay_Log_Space: 154
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: Yes
           Master_SSL_CA_File: C:\work\primary_ca.pem
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2003
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master '15000@xx.xxx.xx.X:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 210126 00:06:31
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
```

on-prem master server configuration -

```
+---------------+
| version()     |
+---------------+
| 5.7.25-28-log |
+---------------+
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO provides help in database admin questions like this.

Comment: thank you I have posted there

Comment: Can you pls remove it from here then?